# Using Alamofire with .publishDecodable

Tags: swift, alamofire, combine

I need to use .publishDecodable together with Result, I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-alamofire-with-combine), but I ran into this error: "generic parameter 't' could not be inferred closure"

[image]

```
@Published var loginModel: [LoginModel] = [LoginModel]()

var cancellation: AnyCancellable?

func request<T: Codable>(_ url: String, method: HTTPMethod = .get, headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil, parameters: Codable? = nil) -> AnyPublisher<Result<T, AFError>, Never> {
    let publisher = AF.request(url, method: method, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .publishDecodable(type: T.self)
    return publisher.result()
}

 func login(email: String, password: String) {
    let parameters = LoginParameters(
        email: email,
        password: password
    )

    cancellation = request(serverURL + "login", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
        .sink { [self] response in
            switch response {
            case .success:
                loginModel = response.value()
            case .failure(error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should help the compiler to infer the `T` type be providing the type of the `response` that you expect. For example your call to `request(_:method:headers:parameters:)` function might look like this:

```
cancellation = request(serverURL + "login", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
    .sink { [self] (response: Result<[LoginModel], AFError>) in
        switch response {
        case .success(let value):
            self.loginModel = value
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Or if you prefer you can specify the return type of the `request(_:method:headers:parameters:)` function like this:

```
let publisher: AnyPublisher<Result<[LoginModel], AFError>, Never>
publisher = request(serverURL + "login", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
cancellation = publisher.sink { [self] response in
    switch response {
    case .success(let value):
        self.loginModel = value
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```